# Array out of bounds? Why?

Tags: c#, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

Currently designing an application that will compute for  the sale of salesment for 4 month given an initial sale.  The sale is expected to raise by 5% every month in 4 months.
ProduceSalesProjectionTable function seems to be giving me an out of bound error and i don't know why can't seem to figure it out.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace itse
{
    class TempAgency
    {
        static string[] salesman1 = new string[4];
        static double[,] sales1 = new double[4, 5];
        static void DisplayInstructions()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You will be asked to enter data for four salesmen.");
            Console.WriteLine("For their name, enter their first name followed");
            Console.WriteLine("by a space and then their las name.");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("For testing purposes enter data for four <4> salesmen.");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }

        static void GetSalesData(string[] salesman, double[,] sales) 
        {
        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter name: ");
                salesman[x] = Console.ReadLine();
                string [] split = salesman[x].Split(new Char [] {' '});
                Console.WriteLine(split[0]+"'s Sales goal: ");
                sales[x,0]=Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        }
        static void ProduceSalesProjectionTable(double[,] sales)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                double salesPercentage = 0.05;
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; i++)
                {

                    sales[i, j + 1] = sales[i, 0] + (sales[i, 0] * salesPercentage);          //here lies the problem 
                    salesPercentage += 0.05;
                }
            }



        }
        static void DisplaySalesProjections()
        { 

        }

        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {

            DisplayInstructions();
            GetSalesData(salesman1, sales1);
            //Console.WriteLine("salesman: " + salesman[0]);
            //Console.WriteLine("sales: " + sales[0, 0]);
            ProduceSalesProjectionTable(sales1);
            //for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            //{
            //    //double salesPercentage = 0.05;
            //    for (int j = 0; j < 4; i++)
            //    {
            //        Console.WriteLine("salesman:  " + salesman[i] + "\tsales: " + sales[i, j]);
            //    }
            //}
            //Console.WriteLine("sales:" + sales[0, 1]);
            //Console.WriteLine("sales:" + sales[1, 1]);
            //Console.WriteLine("sales:" + sales[2, 1]);
            //Console.WriteLine("sales:" + sales[3, 1]);
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                //double salesPercentage = 0.05;
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("salesman:  " + salesman1[i] + "\tsales: " +     sales1[i, 0]);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `for (int j = 0; j < 4; i++)` is most likely the problem and a typo.

Comment: Well, you should start by examining the line that throws the exception! But do you check the length of the `split` array? Perhaps it is empty?

Comment: And as another side note, you probably shouldn't use an arbitrarily fixed length for either i or j in your "for" stop condition. Why not use instead the length of the array ?

Comment: There is no problem with the GetSalesData funtion.  The problem lies in the ProduceSalesProjectionTable funtion.

Comment: screwing yourself by using one char named increments. so common :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look carefully at the line

```
for (int j = 0; j < 4; i++)
```

Your indexer is **j** but you are increasing **i** instead of j.

Eventually `sales[i, j + 1]` evaluates to `sales[4, 1]` which is out of bounds.

Solution: change your code to

```
for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
```

(You have done this in 2 places)

Answer (score 0):

If you build your for-loops like this, there should be no "out of bound error":

```
static void ProduceSalesProjectionTable(double[,] sales)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sales1.GetLength(0); i++)
        {             
            for (int j = 0; j < sales1.GetLength(1); i++)
            {
                ...Do Stuff...
            }
        }
    }
```

When you use 2-dimensional arrays **GetLength(0)** gives you the length of the first dimension of your 2-dimensional array and **GetLength(1)** gives you the length of he second dimension.